# Reduce file size of GSL library

Tags: c++, math, gsl

Is there a way to reduce the file size of the compiled GSL library?

Could I just compile some of the sub-libs?

Comment: how many libs do you need? you could just take the libs you need?

Comment: This question is really interesting. There is a similar question already in stackoverflow, it may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119726/extracting-small-parts-of-large-library-fx-boost I am looking forward to seeing experienced programmers' answers.

Comment: A way to reduce the size of your **executables** is described [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Reducing_Executable_Size). It increases the size of your library though and doesn't tell you how to filter out those parts of the library you are not interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of these ways in which you can get around this -

- A very simple but very effective way to do this is by using dynamic linking. Statically linking code to either your libraries or executables makes them substantially larger. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140061/when-to-use-dynamic-vs-static-libraries) discussion will probably give you a clearer picture. GSL is built as a dynamic library, so  in most cases, you actually have very little of the GSL object files in your own executable files.
- Use compiler optimisations - Strip the binaries using the `-s` and `-Os` flag while compiling(using GCC) or use `strip --strip-all`